# Sublime Text like Ctrl-Delete/Backspace

Tags: functions, defun

Is there any easy way (or maybe a package) which provides `Ctrl-Del/Backspace` behavior like in Sublime?
The default rule of sublime is `delete-to-next-word-boundary`. I did not find similar options. Emacs kinda delete too much for my taste.

#### Sublime Text Example

```
("C-h" . neotree-hidden-file-toggle)
("< |
```

Hit `Ctrl-Backspace`

```
("C-h" . neotree-hidden-file-toggle)
|
```

Hit `Ctrl-Backspace`

```
("C-h" . neotree-hidden-file-toggle)
```

#### Emacs Example

```
("C-h" . neotree-hidden-file-toggle)
("< |
```

Hit `Ctrl-Backspace`

```
("C-h" . neotree-hidden-file-
```

Comment: I haven't tried [this package](https://github.com/kodx/emacs.d/blob/master/plugins/syntax-subword/syntax-subword.el), but it looks like it might be of use to you.

Comment: Btw, if I wanted to delete what you deleted in the first `Ctrl-Backspace` in the Sublime Text example, by habit, I would just do `C-a C-k`  or `C-SPC C-a` (followed by whatever I needed to type instead as I have `delete-selection-mode` enabled.)

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?